# Meaning of 私は　ひらがなが　書けるように　なりました

Tags: meaning, parsing

As the title states, what is the meaning of  私{わたし｝は　ひらがなが　書｛か｝けるように　なりました？

I thought it meant "I felt like writing hiragana", but I am not sure.

Comment: Can't this be solved by using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/)?

Comment: @macraf Unusually, Google Translate gets this right, but you don't learn anything from using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A verb in potential form + ようになる means "To become able to do verb".

書く (to write) -> 書ける (to be able to write) -> 書けるようになる (to come to be able to write).